# Scoped interrupts, do they exist?

Tags: java, networking, concurrency, locking, css-selectors

I'm in requirement of some system to give me scoped interrupts, such that interrupting a thread is disabled when Thread.sleep(..) isn't executing. I'd normally use guarded blocks which would work fine, but there's a few reasons why I can't in this case, mainly because contention prevents the entire thing from working properly. The simulation just freezes up in a few seconds. Scoped interrupts would replace any blocking mechanism and prevent the interrupt from 'leaking' outside the method which the interrupt is being tested on. In this case, it'd be `Thread.sleep(...)`. However, I'm wonder if this is asking for something which is fundamentally impossible in Java. Maybe the guarded blocking mechanism is the best that can be done.

I've created my own implementation of a Selector for use on a network simulator (the selector interacts with simulator callbacks and such for optimisation), and basically I'm using a `CountDownLatch` at the moment. This is good in some situations, while in others it creates *even worse* blocking, while not freezing up the entire simulation per-se (however, it is so slow as to be unworkable). Depends on the networking framework used as to what parts of the code get hit more than others. I also think that in the 'good' simulations the problem may arise, rarely, causing waits of 13ms and so while the internal CountDownLatch is acquired or whatever magic goes on within.

If you can solve the issue without any of the above suggestions, that'd be amazing :) Anyway, my code is below:

```
/**
 *
 */
package kokunet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import kokuks.IConnectionSocket;
import kokuks.KKSAddress;
import kokuks.KKSSocket;
import kokuks.KKSSocketListener;

public class KSelector extends SelectorImpl {
    // True if this Selector has been closed
    private volatile boolean closed = false;

    // Lock for close and cleanup
    final class CloseLock {}
    private final Object closeLock = new CloseLock();

    private volatile boolean selecting = false;
    private volatile boolean wakeup = false;

    class SocketListener implements KKSSocketListener {
        protected volatile CountDownLatch latch = null;

        /**
         *
         */
        public SocketListener() {
            newLatch();
        }

        protected synchronized CountDownLatch newLatch() {
            return this.latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        }

        protected synchronized void refreshReady(KKSSocket socket) {
            if (!selecting) return;

            synchronized (socketToChannel) {
                SelChImpl ch = socketToChannel.get(socket);
                if (ch == null) {
                    System.out.println("ks sendCB: channel not found for socket: " + socket);
                    return;
                }
                synchronized (channelToKey) {
                    SelectionKeyImpl sk = channelToKey.get(ch);
                    if (sk != null) {
                        if (handleSelect(sk)) {
                            latch.countDown();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void connectionSucceeded(KKSSocket socket) {
            refreshReady(socket);
        }
        @Override
        public void connectionFailed(KKSSocket socket) {
            refreshReady(socket);
        }
        @Override
        public void dataSent(KKSSocket socket, long bytesSent) {
            refreshReady(socket);
        }
        @Override
        public void sendCB(KKSSocket socket, long bytesAvailable) {
            refreshReady(socket);
        }
        @Override
        public void onRecv(KKSSocket socket) {
            refreshReady(socket);
        }
        @Override
        public void newConnectionCreated(KKSSocket socket, KKSSocket newSocket, KKSAddress remoteaddress) {
            refreshReady(socket);
        }
        @Override
        public void normalClose(KKSSocket socket) {
            wakeup();
        }
        @Override
        public void errorClose(KKSSocket socket) {
            wakeup();
        }
    }

    protected final Map<KKSSocket, SelChImpl>        socketToChannel = new HashMap<KKSSocket, SelChImpl>();
    protected final Map<SelChImpl, SelectionKeyImpl> channelToKey    = new HashMap<SelChImpl, SelectionKeyImpl>();
    protected final SocketListener currListener = new SocketListener();

    SelChImpl getChannelForSocket(KKSSocket s) {
        synchronized (socketToChannel) {
            return socketToChannel.get(s);
        }
    }

    SelectionKeyImpl getSelKeyForChannel(KKSSocket s) {
        synchronized (channelToKey) {
            return channelToKey.get(s);
        }
    }

    protected boolean markRead(SelectionKeyImpl impl) {
        synchronized (impl) {
            if (!impl.isValid()) return false;
            impl.nioReadyOps(impl.readyOps() | SelectionKeyImpl.OP_READ);
            return selectedKeys.add(impl);
        }
    }

    protected boolean markWrite(SelectionKeyImpl impl) {
        synchronized (impl) {
            if (!impl.isValid()) return false;
            impl.nioReadyOps(impl.readyOps() | SelectionKeyImpl.OP_WRITE);
            return selectedKeys.add(impl);
        }
    }

    protected boolean markAccept(SelectionKeyImpl impl) {
        synchronized (impl) {
            if (!impl.isValid()) return false;
            impl.nioReadyOps(impl.readyOps() | SelectionKeyImpl.OP_ACCEPT);
            return selectedKeys.add(impl);
        }
    }

    protected boolean markConnect(SelectionKeyImpl impl) {
        synchronized (impl) {
            if (!impl.isValid()) return false;
            impl.nioReadyOps(impl.readyOps() | SelectionKeyImpl.OP_CONNECT);
            return selectedKeys.add(impl);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param provider
     */
    protected KSelector(SelectorProvider provider) {
        super(provider);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see kokunet.SelectorImpl#implClose()
     */
    @Override
    protected void implClose() throws IOException {
        provider().getApp().printMessage("implClose: closed: " + closed);
        synchronized (closeLock) {
            if (closed) return;
            closed = true;
            for (SelectionKey sk : keys) {
                provider().getApp().printMessage("dereg1");
                deregister((AbstractSelectionKey)sk);
                provider().getApp().printMessage("dereg2");
                SelectableChannel selch = sk.channel();
                if (!selch.isOpen() && !selch.isRegistered())
                    ((SelChImpl)selch).kill();
            }
            implCloseInterrupt();
        }
    }

    protected void implCloseInterrupt() {
        wakeup();
    }

    private boolean handleSelect(SelectionKey k) {
        synchronized (k) {
            boolean notify = false;

            if (!k.isValid()) {
                k.cancel();
                ((SelectionKeyImpl)k).channel.socket().removeListener(currListener);
                return false;
            }

            SelectionKeyImpl ski = (SelectionKeyImpl)k;

            if ((ski.interestOps() & SelectionKeyImpl.OP_READ) != 0) {
                if (ski.channel.socket().getRxAvailable() > 0) {
                    notify |= markRead(ski);
                }
            }

            if ((ski.interestOps() & SelectionKeyImpl.OP_WRITE) != 0) {
                if (ski.channel.socket().getTxAvailable() > 0) {
                    notify |= markWrite(ski);
                }
            }

            if ((ski.interestOps() & SelectionKeyImpl.OP_CONNECT) != 0) {
                if (!ski.channel.socket().isConnectionless()) {
                    IConnectionSocket cs = (IConnectionSocket)ski.channel.socket();
                    if (!ski.channel.socket().isAccepting() && !cs.isConnecting() && !cs.isConnected()) {
                        notify |= markConnect(ski);
                    }
                }
            }

            if ((ski.interestOps() & SelectionKeyImpl.OP_ACCEPT) != 0) {
                //provider().getApp().printMessage("accept check: ski: " + ski + ", connectionless: " + ski.channel.socket().isConnectionless() + ", listening: " + ski.channel.socket().isListening() + ", hasPendingConn: " + (ski.channel.socket().isConnectionless() ? "nope!" : ((IConnectionSocket)ski.channel.socket()).hasPendingConnections()));
                if (!ski.channel.socket().isConnectionless() && ski.channel.socket().isListening()) {
                    IConnectionSocket cs = (IConnectionSocket)ski.channel.socket();
                    if (cs.hasPendingConnections()) {
                        notify |= markAccept(ski);
                    }
                }
            }
            return notify;
        }
    }

    private boolean handleSelect() {
        boolean notify = false;

        // get initial status
        for (SelectionKey k : keys) {
            notify |= handleSelect(k);
        }

        return notify;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see kokunet.SelectorImpl#doSelect(long)
     */
    @Override
    protected int doSelect(long timeout) throws IOException {
        processDeregisterQueue();

        long timestartedms = System.currentTimeMillis();

        synchronized (selectedKeys) {
            wakeup = false;
            selecting = true;
            try {
                handleSelect();

                if (!selectedKeys.isEmpty() || timeout == 0) {
                    return selectedKeys.size();
                }

                //TODO: useless op if we have keys available
                for (SelectionKey key : keys) {
                    ((SelectionKeyImpl)key).channel.socket().addListener(currListener);
                }
                try {
                    while (!wakeup && isOpen() && selectedKeys.isEmpty()) {
                        CountDownLatch latch = null;
                        synchronized (currListener) {
                            if (wakeup || !isOpen() || !selectedKeys.isEmpty()) {
                                break;
                            }
                            latch = currListener.newLatch();
                        }
                        try {
                            if (timeout > 0) {
                                long currtimems = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                long remainingMS = (timestartedms + timeout) - currtimems;

                                if (remainingMS > 0) {
                                    latch.await(remainingMS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                                } else {
                                    break;
                                }
                            } else {
                                latch.await();
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            wakeup();
                        }
                    }
                    return selectedKeys.size();
                } finally {
                    for (SelectionKey key : keys) {
                        ((SelectionKeyImpl)key).channel.socket().removeListener(currListener);
                    }
                    processDeregisterQueue();
                }
            } finally {
                selecting = false;
                wakeup = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see kokunet.SelectorImpl#implRegister(kokunet.SelectionKeyImpl)
     */
    @Override
    protected void implRegister(SelectionKeyImpl ski) {
        synchronized (closeLock) {
            if (closed) throw new ClosedSelectorException();
            synchronized (channelToKey) {
                synchronized (socketToChannel) {
                    keys.add(ski);
                    socketToChannel.put(ski.channel.socket(), ski.channel);
                    channelToKey.put(ski.channel, ski);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see kokunet.SelectorImpl#implDereg(kokunet.SelectionKeyImpl)
     */
    @Override
    protected void implDereg(SelectionKeyImpl ski) throws IOException {
        synchronized (channelToKey) {
            synchronized (socketToChannel) {
                keys.remove(ski);
                socketToChannel.remove(ski.channel.socket());
                channelToKey.remove(ski.channel);

                SelectableChannel selch = ski.channel();

                if (!selch.isOpen() && !selch.isRegistered())
                    ((SelChImpl)selch).kill();
            }
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see kokunet.SelectorImpl#wakeup()
     */
    @Override
    public Selector wakeup() {
        synchronized (selectedKeys) {
            wakeup = true;
            selectedKeys.notifyAll();
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Sorry for not posting an SCEE in this case, but in this case it's a bit difficult. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Scoped interrupts do not exist.

However, when a `sleep` or `wait` or whatever terminates with an `InterruptedException` the "interrupted" flag will have been cleared before the exception is thrown.  So if you catch the exception at some block boundary you've sort of got scoping.  Similarly, `Thread.interrupted()` tests *and clears* the "interrupted" flag.

---

On reading your code more carefully, I realize that you are (in fact) not using interrupts at all.  Rather you are using `notify` and `notify` only wakes up a thread that is executing a `wait`.

Comment: The problem is the granularity of the scope when it comes to the interrupt -- it keeps leaking into the parent try/catch, because it's impossible to tell whether I'm inside interruptible code or not within the defined scope. Like I say, I need to avoid the guarded block mechanism because it doesn't work in this case. It's a real headbanger. Something involving LockSupport.park(..) might work, which is the skeleton of synchronisation constructs.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualising what you suggest, although it sounds good :) I'm wondering if the interrupted() flag really can help prevent leaking of the interrupt into the parent exception catcher.

Comment: @Chris - Look at the javadocs for the methods that throw `InterruptedException`

Comment: @Chris - I'm not saying that this is real scoping: it is not.  Rather, I'm saying that this is as close as you are likely to get.